# Local Co-ordinate of Image view w.r.t to the root View

Tags: android, android-layout

I have relative layout as a main View and it has few Image views which are place w.r.t to margin top and margin left. Now I want to check the imageViews opacity or transparent region  at the pixel where touch is happened. Say I touched some where 533,240 .. I want to check whether that position is transparent or transculent or opaque.. Since imageview will always be square and i guess there will be part of image will be transparent but it should not be included in onTouch event thats why I aim for this that if i get the position of my touch w.r.t to local co-ordinate of the Imageview then I can give that pixel to the drawable.getTransparentRegion.container(int x , int y )

Explaining further.. .what I am  trying to do is I am getting View on click or on touch.. From that view I am getting imageview ....and from that imageview I am trying to get Drawable of that imageview ..I have reached till here ... Now I want to get the touch event position w.r.t to the imageview so I can check it in drawable.getTransparentRegion ? ... I hope you understood

At the end I want to differentiate between the transparent part of the imageView i.e.(not needed part of the Imageview ) and the Transculent part that will be there of the drawable in the imageView...

Answer (score 0):

get coordinates of imageview on window by

```
public void getLocationInWindow (int[] location),
```

pass integer array of two size to this method. Invoke this method after layout has been drawn, use location array to get imageview's left and top co-ordinates, add transparent co-ordinates to it, and you will get co-ordinates which can be compared to touchevent co-ordinates.